# Desktop Icon in Linux

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, desktop

I am running Linux and in particular, a project to first of all detect the rf spectrum, then a second file to send a preamble and a third to send some data on the optimum frequency.  This is achieved through a mixture of python and sh files which are all chmod +x.

The whole procedure works well when I run the first file through cli,however, I have now attempted to create a desktop icon for ease of use and demonstration similar to below:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=helloworld
Comment=
Exec=./test.py
Icon=
Path=/home/xxx/Desktop
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=false
```

When I now start the process using the desktop icon it will only open the first python file.  All of the links remain but they do not run.  Is there something significant that I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a rather unconventional use of .desktop files. Normally you'd specify either an absolute path to the executable, or just the name, in the hope that $PATH would find it. I don't think any guarantee is given that invoking the desktop icon would set any particular working directory, so I would guess the various bits of your application can't find one another.

The usual way of getting around problems like this in Linux, when one application has to invoke another, is to make sure that all the parts are in $PATH. As that is often impractical, a common approach is to have the first application part use readlink() on /proc/self/exe to find its own filesystem location, and then parse that to work out where the rest of the bits are. Typically they are in the same directory. So we find the absolute path by removing the final, filename part of the first executable's full path, and substituting the new filename.

There are similar ways to do the same thing, but all involve working with absolute, known pathnames, rather that relying on the desktop to do the right thing. The desktop might do the right thing sometimes, but it won't be portable.